# Drawing multiple sprites with clear screen for every frame

Tags: 2d, animation, sprites, game-loop, sfml

I googled with best of my skills, but I cannot find any relevant answer to my problem. I'm making a game with an isometric view. I need to draw multiple sprites on the screen and before switching to next frame of the sprite, it is needed to  clear the last frame of the sprite by doing a `clearScreen` of the window. If I do `clearScreen`, all of the other sprites get cleared, since the program cannot remember the last state of the screen. How can I overcome this problem?

Here is my code (I'm writing in pseudo-code, so that the solution can become implementation independent)

```
main.cpp
{
  //gameloop 

 Animation playerAnimation;

  while(window.isopen())
  {
    window.draw(game_map);

   if(certain_condition_is_met)
   playerAnimation.update(window)

    window.clear()
    window.display();
  }
}

   Animation.cpp

   class Animation
   {
     void update(&window) 
      {
        for(available_frames frame)
         window.draw(frame);
       //inside the above for loop ,i need to do a clearscreen to avoid overlap of 
       //frames,but this will make other sprites to be lost 
       }
   }
```

I'm using C++ SFML, in which there is no way to update a particular sprite without `clearScreen`.

Comment: You are trying to play the entire animation in one frame? Is that necessary for your game?

Comment: no .. that is not at all necessary

Comment: ok. You need a variable to keep track of what frame you are on in your update function. Only draw the frame you are on each update. That way you are only drawing the sprite once per update. Then you only need to clear the screen once (per update).

Comment: learn how loops actually work and you will see your problem

Answer (score 0):

In case you needed a code example

```
class Animation
{
    void update()
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            advanceFrame();
        }
        frame.draw();
    }
}

Animation animation;

int main()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        animation.update();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

The condition is most likely a timer, to update the animation every few milliseconds.
This way, the animation is drawn once per update.